# How to remove href="x-default" from Joomla Website?

Tags: joomla, tags

I'm doing the SEO for my Website and I found that all the pages of my Joomla Website have beside the hreflang="en" tag that I set also a hreflang="x-default".

Is there a way to deactivate the x-default hreflang tag from a Joomla Site?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under "Extensions" -> "Plugins", search for "System - Language Filter", click on it, and then choose "No" next to " Add x-default Meta Tag", save the plugin, and then clear your Joomla and your browser cache. This should do it.